# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'value' not found

Tags: r, linear-regression

I think this may be too easy for all of you, but it is driving me crazy and I googled for straight 2 hours now, but I cannot solve this. I just started using R today and just trying to do a simple LM to get started.
This is my code:

```
library(readxl)
IPO <- read_excel("C:/Test.xlsx", sheet = "Tabelle1",
                col_types = c("text","numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
results <- lm(value~Age+Education)
```

So, I just import my data from an XLS file using readxl, which works and I get my data, as IPO is now listed under "Data".

But if I run the linear regression command, I get this error:
"Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'value' not found"

I know that "Value" is not listed as a Value in R, but how can I change this?
I was using this video as reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-zKhFr91Tg&t=253s

When he runs the lm command, the Field "Values" (I know it`s the same name, but this is coincidence) the header "Values" under "Data" is created automatically - this does not happen when I try it.

Help?!

The Data:
https://pastebin.com/rdWYpBPR

Sorry, if this is too easy to ask. I just don´t know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lm(Value~Age+Education, data = IPO)`, uppercase matters, and you need to add the data part as well

Comment: Oh, did I really just forget data = IPO?

Comment: This was just the error it seems - where can I learn to find this on my own, that I was missing data = IPO? Can you pinpoint me somewhere? Thank you so much for the quick help!

Comment: Type `?lm` in the R console